# is Bootstrap configuration mandatory to run dynamic project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

To run dynamic project in **eclipse**, I have already added required jars in project class path, some jars path are reference from other open project. even though it is throw **class not found** error. when I put that jars in bootstrap entries, it works fine.

So my questions are:

1) Is Bootstrap configuration mandatory to run dynamic project?

2) Why does it not find class path while running server?

3) How can I run my project without configuring Bootstrap entries?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must not be put in the build classpath, neither under *User entries*, nor under *Bootstrap entries*.

It must be dropped inside the `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` directory of your webapp project. Eclipse will detect them, automatically add them into the build path for you, and automatically include them into the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of the *deployed* webapp, since that's where the Java EE containers look for the libraries needed by a Java EE webapp.

Comment: Thanks, It works. but is it mandatory that all library should in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib? Because a other project have those library, and I add that jar path in my project. and also that project is opened. i.e. A project jar lib path used in B project path.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. But your container doesn't care what the *build* classpath of your project is. What matters for the container is the *runtime* classpath of the app, and this classpath is constituted by all the jar files under WEB-INF/lib. That's what the JEE specification says.